# XML to Excel Help - Why I am not able to get proper mapping from schema that I made?

Tags: excel, xml, xsd

Firstly, I don't have any experience in XML writing. Due to some tasks in my Company, I decided to learn it a bit, and this is my second day.

This is the code which I used as a practice:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name ="fruits">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="fruit" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name ="fruit">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name ="name"/>
            <xs:element name ="color"/>
            <xs:element name ="growsOn"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and this is what I am getting in Excel

[image: Excel]

So,as I said. I just want to know where I made mistake and why is shown wrongly in Excel? Shouldn't be 3 columns (name, color and growsOn)??? Btw., this was just a dummy example for me to understand it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An XSD is an XML document that contains the rules for a whole family of XML documents. So you can load it into Excel (just like any other XML document).

You have loaded an *XML Schema (XSD)* into Excel. I think you intended to load an *XML document*.